# Problem with ShareKit twitter and UIWebView (no keyboard)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, keyboard, twitter, uikeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard not Appearing when Tapping Text Box in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312680/keyboard-not-appearing-when-tapping-text-box-in-uiwebview)

I was implementing ShareKit in my application to allow posting to twitter. However when the login field for Twitter appears, which is in a UIWebView, there is no keyboard. I have had similar issues in the past. Is there a fix/code modification I can apply to the ShareKit source to fix it so the keyboard will show? What causes it?

Comment: I noticed after using some of the other UIWebViews in my application that have forms, and then going back to the twitter page via ShareKit, that the keyboard will appear.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm noticing a similar issue in even non-ShareKit views in 4.2.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the keyboard is popping up behind your webview. Immediately after displaying your UIWebView, try referencing your Application Delegate as appDelegate and then call:

```
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: If you have any other code that makes windows and doesn't properly restore the key window after, you will have this issue. Making your application's window key again is the solution as taintedzodiac said.

Comment: How to access to appDelegate?

Comment: @Altaveron You can use `MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` (You'll need to substitute MyAppDelegate for the actual name of your app delegate, obviously :)